# quiz program Timer issue

Tags: android

I'm creating one quiz application for android in which i am using timer.Based on timer the questions will move to next. There are 20 questions. I am giving 6 seconds of time for each question. They should answer within 6 seconds otherwise the question will move to next question. If they answer in four seconds means that remaining 2 seconds will be added to next question. So that the next question will have 8 seconds of time. Thus i have to add remaining seconds to next question till the end. I used the below code but it has only start and stop the timer.

```
    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        mTimerText.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
};

public void playClock() {
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()==6) {
        getQuestion();   //Here i call my question
    }
}


public void resumeClock() {
    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
}
```

Comment: explain in detail.... after select answer you have to start timmer gain to 0 - 6 second?

Comment: I don't know how to call question every six seconds?

Comment: please rewrite Your question , it is very hard to understand. We really don´t know what exactly You want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `CountDownTimer` try below method startTimmer(6) when timmer complate there is method `finishQuizTime();` is called(set next question detail in that method).

when user select answer call `finishQuizTime();` & stop `CountDownTimer` using `mCountDown.cancel();`

```
/**
     * timer for quiz question
     * */
    public void startTimmer(int currentQueSec) {

        Log.e("start timmer for ", "--->" + currentQueSec);

        mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(currentQueSec, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                /**
                 * stop timmer
                 * */

                finishQuizTime();


                Log.e("time is finish", "time is finish");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                queLastTime = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

            }
        }.start();
    }
```